# ListLinePlot is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, error-tracking, error-propagation

I am getting this error
'ListLinePlot is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers'

However I'm not really sure what it means, the data set is a list of pairs of numbers. Even the more complex version of the graph is a copy and paste of a previous working one with some numbers and the odd line changed.

The documentation doesn't list it as a possible problem, and the error seems incorrect? Am I missing something?

Minimal Example:

````
dataSet = {{352, 16.8}, {669, 13.2}, {726, 12.6}, {1140, 8.9}, {1189, 
    7.7}, {1566, 6.3}};

set[1] = Cases[dataSet, {x_, y_} /; x < 670];
set[2] = Cases[dataSet, {x_, y_} /; 670 < x < 1141];
set[3] = Cases[dataSet, {x_, y_} /; x > 1567];

ListLinePlot[{set[1], set[2], set[3]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1600}, {0, 20}}]
```
````

Comment: The problem is that `set[3]` is empty - if you remove it or do something like `DeleteCases[{}]@{set[1],set[2],set[3]}`, the error goes away (effectively, `ListPlot` can't decide on the shape of the input due to the empty list)

Comment: set[3] is empty. Eliminate it and it works.

Comment: Ah I see... I had the inequality the other way before. 
Does the error message refer specifically to set 3?
If anyone wants to write up the answer. I can mark it and close off the question